# Passing Array data between view controllers

Tags: arrays, swift, modalviewcontroller

I've troubles to pass data stocked in an array between view controllers.

This is my first view controller:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var showDico: ViewControllerShowDico = segue.destinationViewController as ViewControllerShowDico

    showDico.Dico = self.dictionnaire
}
```

And this is the second one:

```
class ViewControllerShowDico: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl_ContenuDico: UILabel!

    var Dico = [String]()
    var i = Int()
    var tailleDico = Int()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        // Calcul de la taille du dictionnaire
        tailleDico = Dico.count

        // Affichage des mots dans le label lbl_contenuDico
        lbl_ContenuDico.text = "\(Dico)"

    }

}
```

This is how my dictionnaire variable is initialize:

```
var dictionnaire = ["Maserati", "Porsche", "Airbus", "Canari", "Automobile",
                    "Jouer", "Pendu", "France"]
```

The problem is that the array in my second view controller contain nothing

Comment: where and how are you assigning self.dictionnaire?

Comment: And what's the type of self.dictionnaire as well?

Comment: `var Dico = [String]()` here you declare an array not a dictionary!

Comment: I want that my Dico variable which is in my second view controller be equal to dictionnaire which is located in my first view controller.

Comment: I don't need a dictionary, I named it like that because I'm making an hangman game so I would like an array to stock all words in it, that's all

Comment: try a `println(self.dictionary)` in the `prepareForSegue:...` method and a `println(Dico)` in the viewDidload method and compare. Do not forget to add super.viewDidLoad() call!

Comment: So again, how are you initializing self.dictionnaire ?

Comment: @JeremyPope that's how I initialize dictionnaire   var dictionnaire = ["Maserati", "Porsche", "Airbus", "Canari", "Automobile",
                        "Jouer", "Pendu", "France"]

Comment: @bsarr007 I've tried. `println(self.dictionnaire)` send back all value but `println(Dico)` doesn't

Comment: I tested the code and it's work fine for me Dico contains all elements!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue with Dico is that when you call the second view controller you are re-initalizing the array with `Dico: [String]()`  when really you just want to declare the structure like this - `Dico: [String]!`